# Authenticate and Authorize Dynamics 365 Portal Contact in custom Application

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, msal.js, adxstudio-portals

It seems it is possible to [create client applications in the Dataverse space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/connect-dataverse) without using Low Code solutions.

For Power App Portals, which has "public" style licensing, the Application User that authenticates is off premise, and linked to a Contact record in the Customer Engagement/Portal applications.

Is it possible to write a Custom application (in JavaScript), authenticating a Customer Engagement Contact, perhaps through Azure AD B2C, OAuth, or even local authentication and access the CE data as them? Can App Permissions be utilized?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure AD, instead of Azure AD B2C, for this scenario as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory) along with your custom JavaScript app.

Comment: I don't think this fits my use case. This is for external, customer facing, portal data and licensing.  The power app portal will associate the login credential with a Contact in dataverse and have appropriate application level permissions. I want to do the same, in a custom js app

Comment: Azure AD B2C will issue a token to a relying party. If this relying party is your custom js application then it can decide how to use it. If your intention is to use a token with some other service/product then you need to confirm with them if they accept token generated Azure AD B2C.

Comment: The stock "power app portal" allows authentication with azure ad b2c, open id connect, etc. it just has some BLL that ties this to the dataverse Contacts. I am trying to leverage this to do an out of box solution.